# (RoR) json and nested objects: get attribute in object of object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

My goal is an output like this (for each attachment):

> url:
>   "/uploads/attachment/picture/15/5ee306c9-e263-466b-b56d-1c7c9d2ae17b.jpg"

What I have at the moment:

[image: json object in object]

attachments_controller.rb

```
class AttachmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user

  def index
    @attachments = current_user.attachments.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        render :json => @attachments.each{ |o| o.picture.url }
      end
    end
  end

...
```

Comment: What does this output at the moment?

Comment: It's for the froala wysiwyg editor: https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/concepts/image-manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json do
    render :json => @attachments.map { |o| { url: o.picture.url } }
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the output: `[{"url":"/uploads/attachment/picture/7/df3c0c3c-518a-44cc-afab-64dc6acb063c.jpg"},{"url":"/uploads/attachment
/picture/12/dd7839ee-94c1-4390-aa5d-a37cccbc3c8a.jpg"} ...`